# Get value from global data

Tags: abap

How to identify the value contained in the following global variable, into `lv_local` variable?

```
data lv_local type string.

lv_local = '(SAPLMIGO)LCL_MIGO_GLOBALS=>KERNEL->S_CONTROL-VGART'.
```

Comment: It seems that you know how to read global variables from another program, so don't you want to ask a question about the real issue (in `MIGO`)?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the variable to a field symbol and read the value out of it.
Example:

```
CONSTANTS: 
lco_migo_vgart_path TYPE string VALUE '(SAPLMIGO)LCL_MIGO_GLOBALS=>KERNEL->S_CONTROL-VGART'.

FIELD-SYMBOLS:
<migo_vgart> TYPE any.

DATA: 
lv_vgart TYPE vgart.

ASSIGN (lco_migo_vgart_path) to <migo_vgart>.
IF sy-subrc = 0.
    lv_vgart = <migo_vgart>.
ENDIF.
```

Be aware that accessing variables from the call stack like this is not ideal for productive usage, so looking for an alternative implementation is strongly recommended.

Comment: As said in the [ABAP doc. of ASSIGN (name) TO ...](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapassign_mem_area_dynamic_dobj.htm) : "**For internal use only**, the name in name can also have the form "(PROG)DOBJ""